# Integrate dialogflow with website widget ui

Tags: web, dialogflow-es

I want to integrate the dialogflow bot I made to a website and change the logo and make it show up when a button is clicked and stay floating 
I tried looking the source code of the webdemo and copy pasted it to my website and edited the img src but didnt work 
any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [kommunicate.io](https://docs.kommunicate.io/docs/web-installation.html) Web API for using your dialogflow app in your website.

You just need to add your kommunicate credentials(APP_ID) in the JavaScript code of your web page to display a widget as you want.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function(d, m){

/*---------------- Kommunicate settings start ----------------*/

 var kommunicateSettings = {
  "appId": "<APP_ID>",
  "conversationTitle":"<CONVERSATION_TITLE>",
  "automaticChatOpenOnNavigation": true,
  "popupWidget": true
  /*
  "onInit": function (){
    // paste your code here
  },
    "botIds":["<BOT_ID_1>","<BOT_ID_2>"]
  */
  };

/*----------------- Kommunicate settings end ------------------*/

 var s = document.createElement("script");
  s.type = "text/javascript";
  s.async = true;
  s.src = "https://widget.kommunicate.io/v2/kommunicate.app";
  var h = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
  h.appendChild(s);
  window.kommunicate = m;
  m._globals = kommunicateSettings;
})(document, window.kommunicate || {});
```

Use [this](https://docs.kommunicate.io/docs/bot-dialogflow-integration#integration-using-dialogflow-v2-apis) guide to integrate Dialogflow.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i think OP wants to add webdemo widget to his own website not kommunicate widget.

Comment: Yeah I need something to use coding in it not using paid service actually

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://board.support/. You just need to click the sync button into the admin area, generate the Refresh Token, and insert the Project ID, after that the Dialogflow bot will start answering the users' questions.

Check this page for more details: https://board.support/dialogflow. Docs at: https://board.support/docs#dialogflow

To display the chat you will need to insert a link to a js file:

```
<script src="supportboard/js/init.js"></script>
```

*Server requirements: PHP 7.2+ and MySQL*

Disclaimer: I work for Support Board